# Vertical Match Box keyboard for Pi

Tags: touchscreen, keyboard, virtualization

I am looking for a vertical virtual keyboard utility for the Pi. I have a 5" touch screen display that is oriented vertically. I needs to show a keyboard on the display. What I really want is something like the google keyboard on an Android phone. I have tried the matchbox keyboard but the keys way too small. Is there something else out there that will look good on a vertical screen?

Comment: Would OnBoard work for you?